# Using domain with serialport-node

Tags: node-serialport

I have the node-serialport library working fine in a happy-path situation, but I'd like to address error handling.

The particular test case I'm addressing at the moment is simply that the serial device isn't plugged in.  Ideally, I'd be able to detect that a problem exists, and then just retry after a short delay.

The problem is that I keep getting the following error:

```
events.js:72
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error: cannot open /dev/ttyACM0
```

I would expect something like this, since the device isn't plugged in, but I need to catch it.  try/catch obviously doesn't work, since it's asynchronous.  So I am trying "domain", which appears to be the recommended way:

```
function reconnect() {
    var d = domain.create();

    d.on("error", function(err) {
        console.error(err);
        setTimeout(reconnect, RETRY_DELAY_MS);
    });

    d.run(function() {
        var gps = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0");

        gps.on("open", function() {
            console.log("Success!");
        });

        gps.on("error", function(err) {
            console.error(err);
            setTimeout(reconnect, RETRY_DELAY_MS);
        });
    });
}
```

I would expect this to have the desired effect, but I get the same error as above.

Does anyone see anything that I'm just not getting?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to provide a callback when instantiating the SerialPort object

```
var serial = new serialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", { baudrate : 115200 },
  function(error) {
     if(error)
     {
      console.log("INIT ERROR: " + error.message + "\n");
     }
});
```